# jquery offset() return empty string in each() in firefox 12

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, each, offset

http://jsfiddle.net/suenot/3b3XM/1/

```
// in FF and IE each() don't work offset()
// $(this).offset().top return empty string
$(document).ready(function(){
    var index = 0;
    $('.box').each(function(){
        var background = $(this).css('background');
        $(this).css('background', 'none');
        var height = $(this).css('height');
        var top = $(this).offset().top;
        $('body').prepend('<div id="box' + ++index + '"></div>');
        $('#box' + index).css({
            'height': height,
            'background': background,
            'position': 'absolute',
            'z-index': '-1',
            'top': top,
            'width': '100%'
        });
    });
});​
```

Help me please, i can't find the solution.

Comment: Just tested in FF 12, and it works fine `.offset().top` returns a value.

Comment: In each() tested? In jsfiddle also work? Sorry for my english.

Comment: please post some code snippets, not just a link to it.

Comment: Yes, I placed a `console.log($(this).offset().top);` inside `.each(..` and it printed all the values.

Comment: The problem is that `$(this).css('background')` returns a blank string.

Comment: I am not sure if `$(this).css('background-color');` is what you want, but that brings out some output in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/3b3XM/4/)

Comment: You are right, problem in this, not in offset().top.

Comment: As Rocket pointed out -> It Seems like `$(this).css('background')` works fine in IE 9 and Chrome, but fails in FF 12 and `$(this).css('background-color');` seems to work across all three browsers.

Comment: Just a nipick: Put `$(this)` into a variable and reference it instead of keep looking it up. That jQuery call is expensive.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if `$(this).css('background-color');` is what you want, but after updating it shows the box. See output in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/3b3XM/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var index = 0;
    $('.box').each(function(){
        var background = $(this).css('background-color');
        $(this).css('background', 'none');
        var height = $(this).css('height');
        var top = $(this).offset().top;
        $('body').prepend('<div id="box' + ++index + '"></div>');
        $('#box' + index).css({
            'height': height,
            'background': background,
            'position': 'absolute',
            'z-index': '-1',
            'top': top,
            'width': '100%'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: +1, this makes the output the same in Firefox 12 and Chrome 19.

Comment: @Rocket Oh i see, `$(this).css('background')` worked fine in Chrome.

Comment: @Rocket tbh, it is an interesting thing to notice.. This question deserves some upvotes if only it was well formatted.